# JPA Query with multiple where clauses and multiple data sets

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql, jparepository

```
@repository    
public interface BookRepository extends JPARepository<BookEntity bookEntity, Integer bookId>{

@Query
("select b from bookEntity b
where b.name=:#{#bookDTO.name}
and b.isbn=:#{#bookDTO.isbn}
... and 3-4 other where clauses
)
public Optional<BookEntity> findByMultipleCols(@Param("bookDTO") BookDTO bookDTO);
```

This works perfectly when I need to run this query only once.
I have a scenario where this query needs to be run multiple times for various sets of BookDTO. More like a List object.

As of now, I am calling this method findByMultipleCols(bookDTO), using a list iterator. Is there any other way to call this method only once and use a List as a @Param?

I am using Spring Boot 3.1.1 version.

```
the search is with the following set
book1-name  author1     200
book1-name  author2     300


database table content:
book1-name  author2     200
book1-name  author2     300
```

If the query runs correctly, the result should be only one row, i.e. the second one.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "IN" in your query like

> ```
> @Repository public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<BookEntity, Integer> {
>
> @Query("SELECT b FROM BookEntity b WHERE b.name IN :#{#bookDTOs.stream().map(BookDTO::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())} AND b.isbn IN :#{#bookDTOs.stream().map(BookDTO::getIsbn).collect(Collectors.toList())} ...")
> List<BookEntity> findByMultipleBooks(@Param("bookDTOs") List<BookDTO> bookDTOs); }
> ```

if your queried tables are large can be useful batch, async or cache

Comment: Will the same BookDTO object be considered for a single run of the query?

Comment: Also, Yes. The tables are huge. How to utilize batch, async or cache?

Comment: let me explain for you;
if your BookDTO objects have fields like name and isbn, the query will collect all the name values and all the isbn values from every BookDTO in the list then 
the IN clause in the query checks if the name and isbn of each record in the BookEntity table match any of the name and isbn values in the provided lists
that means that query is effectively a single operation that checks for matches against all the provided BookDTO obects at onee

Comment: which one is suitable for the project? what do you want to use?
if that Book datas has data that dos not change much u can use cache with redis, etc.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please look at the actual database content and my expectation. As per the in clause, I think both the rows would be returned instead of just one?